# Never got a shirt; too late?

Tags: discussion, t-shirt

Do the Stack Overflow shirts still exist? I just saw a picture of [Dalgas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2/geoff-dalgas) with his shirt on, and the envy within me came alive. Is it too late to get a nice, black, Stack Overflow shirt? I'm willing to pay if necessary.

[image: Geoff Dalgas]

Comment: I'm glad you didn't see a picture of Dalgas with his shirt _off_.

Comment: @Changing: I expected that comment :)

Comment: @Jonathan - And yet you didn't change the wording at all... I would say that my suspicions are aroused but that would veer off into even worse territory.

Comment: @Changing: I expected it once I read it after posting. I can't say your choice of words is any better :)

Comment: I got mine last week, so they definitely exist (deleted reply, since you commented that you got the e-mail)

Comment: Where's the SF love???

Comment: Seriously.  There's your VC money right there.  Sell shirts.  And cookies.

Comment: @Chris: If I'm not mistaken, the shirts preceded the VC-talk.

Comment: Coffee mugs.  Coffee mugs.  Coffee mugs.  Coffee mugs.  Coffee mugs.  Coffee mugs.  Coffee mugs.  Coffee mugs.  Coffee mugs.  Coffee mugs.  Coffee mugs.  Coffee mugs.  Coffee mugs.  Coffee mugs.  Coffee mugs.  Coffee mugs.  Coffee mugs.  Coffee mugs.  Coffee mugs.  Coffee mugs.  Coffee mugs.  Coffee mugs.  Coffee mugs.  Coffee mugs.

Comment: You're right, the shirts were before the (public, at least) VC talk.  I just want one, too!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45782/t-shirt-time-beta

Comment: @squillman: i don't think you need any more coffee.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

I got mine.

Comment: Is this your "I ordered black, Jeff" face? :)

Comment: No, this is my "help, my work area is flooded with bright sunshine" face.

Answer (score 4):

I knew I shouldn't have weaned myself from SO!

Oh well, at least I have my stickers to comfort me.

<sup>*my precious...*</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I'll follow up with the shirts -- I know some users in the USA have gotten them already, but I'm not sure how much international shipping delays everything.

Comment: @Jeff, Where can I request a shirt from now for international shipping, if possible? I missed some posts about shirts.

Comment: @Jeff: just got my shirt yesterday in its "Small Flat Rate Box" package, sent to France. Thank you :)

Comment: Don't forget about 1st page meta users! We are important too!

Comment: So how do we get one of these shirts!?

Comment: check out my answer with links below...

Comment: more more more :D

Answer (score 2):

see this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45782/t-shirt-time-beta

and you can order your shirts here through Amazon Checkout: http://inedomedia.com/store/stackoverflowstore.aspx

Comment: Order link isn't working =(

Comment: @Justin L.: my post is pretty old...ya, the purchase site has been **taken down...** so it will probably be up again when they are ready to start selling items...

Answer (score 1):

> SO shirts. Awesome!!
>   How can i get?

P.S. I am no 'SO developer', moderator or Jon Skeet :-).

Answer (score 1):

They do exist, and we *did* try to mail you one: [9101010521297786600427](http://trkcnfrm1.smi.usps.com/PTSInternetWeb/InterLabelInquiry.do?origTrackNum=9101010521297786600427).

It's been on my list to track you down, but now that I've got your attention... do you have an alternate address? We could try sending it to the same one again... but that usually doesn't work.

Comment: Wait, t-shirts were sent out? To whom? How do I get one?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>*Ahem...*</sub> He is one of the developers, does it surprise you at all that he got one of the shirts before everybody else?

Comment: Not at all. Page 1 users (and Mods) were contacted in Feb. I was curious if the boat had left dock or not.

Comment: I hate these kind of things don't apply to meta =(

Comment: I would wear my "I got to the front page of Meta and all I got was this lousy t-shirt" shirt with PRIDE!

Comment: @Jonathan, not only has the boat left the dock, but Atwood is programming on it.

Answer (score -1):

I forgot about this.  Have any other UK (or EU) front-page SO people got their free shirt yet? I haven't.

**And not only do I not get a shirt, but I get all my posts here closed by Atwood!**

Comment: Well, I haven't closed this one ... yet.

Comment: @Jeff Well, I haven't got a shirt ... yet.

Comment: I will follow up on the shirts for sure.

Comment: They were sent out. Unfortunately, the USPS does not provide usable tracking numbers to UK, so we can't see what happened to yours. Let me know if you don't see it in the next week or two, as it seems there's a relatively low success rate (98% based on past exp) of packages making it there.

Comment: @Neil: just received mine yesterday. In France.

Comment: Neil: what do you expect when someone involved in delivery will be on strike...

Comment: @gbn Who's on strike? The BA strike, if that is what you are referring to, is by cabin crew, not baggage handlers, and in any case has only just started.